# Is the quality of a PRNG's distribution ideally the same for all seeds?

Tags: random

Putting cryptographic standards of quality aside (difficulty in predicting previous and next outputs from a current one, etc.), and focusing more on e.g. testing and games where randomness makes things exhaustive or fun, so repetitions or similarity of outputs are not desirable.

For a function `random(s)` which is an *ideal-quality* PRNG (real PRNGs may be poor) that produces a set of outputs, is `random(1)`, `random(2)` etc. hypothetically as equally useful as `random(H)` where H comes from some hardware generated randomness like `/dev/random`?

My intuition says that it ought to be, and this would be why using the system clock is often just a convenient way to get a different number on separate runs without needing to store it.

Comment: What is an "ideal quality" PRNG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If security isn't a concern then it shouldn't matter how you seed it. A high-quality PRNG defines a large pseudorandom cycle (or perhaps set of cycles) which have the same uniform distribution no matter where you enter the cycle. You are correct that seeding such a thing from the system clock is not an external source of randomness that the PRNG depends upon to behave properly but is rather mostly just a convenient way of entering the cycle at a different point in each run.